# Compare Datatype in C#

Tags: c#, compare

I'd like to compare the data types of two classes and return bool values. The problem is my method doesn't compare values inside class of a class

Here is the code:

```
public static class Compare
{
    public static bool PublicInstancePropertiesEqual<T>(this T self, T to, params string[] ignore) where T : class
    {
        if (self != null && to != null)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            var ignoreList = new List<string>(ignore);
            var unequalProperties =
                from pi in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                where !ignoreList.Contains(pi.Name)
                let selfValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(self, null)
                let toValue = type.GetProperty(pi.Name).GetValue(to, null)
                where selfValue != toValue && (selfValue == null || !selfValue.Equals(toValue))
                select selfValue;
            return !unequalProperties.Any();
        }
        return self == to;
    }
}
```

And here is the comparison:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Obj1 obj1 = new Obj1();
        Obj1 obj11 = new Obj1();
        Obj2 obj2 = new Obj2();
        Obj2 obj22 = new Obj2();

        obj1.param1 = "1";
        obj1.param2 = "2";

        obj2.param3 = "3";
        obj1.obj2 = obj2;

        obj11.param1 = "1";
        obj11.param2 = "2";
        obj22.param3 = "3";
        obj11.obj2 = obj22;
        bool res = Compare.PublicInstancePropertiesEqual(obj1, obj11, ("secure"));

    }
}
class Obj1
{
    public string param1 { get; set; }
    public string param2 { get; set; }
    public Obj2 obj2 { get; set; }
}
class Obj2
{
    public string param3 { get; set; }
    public decimal param4 { get; set; }

}
```

The returned value is false by res

Comment: Have you debugged to see why it doesn't work?

Comment: Instead of calling selfValue.Equals(toValue) you should call your own PublicInstancePropertiesEqual method, of course you'll need to add some checks for valuetypes in that case I suppose

Comment: Test each property manually, to see which one fails the comparison. then for that property, test each of the 3 parts of your comparison condition to see which one is true or false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you come to compare the two instances of `Obj2` they will only be equal if they are the same object.

To perform structural equality you need to recurse through all reference types (ie. classes), just directly comparing value types (ie. structs, which use structural equality by default). Note `int` etc. are value types.

I would suggest checking for types that overrides [`Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47), implement [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx), [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) etc.: all the indications that a type has its own definition of equal.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the values of obj1.obj2 and obj11.obj2 are different and the comparison method uses Object.Equals to compare members of the classes, which is why the Compare.PublicInstancePropertiesEqual method returns false.

I.e.:  obj1.obj2 = obj2; but obj11.obj2 = obj22;

If you would like to compare values recursively, you should replace the line

```
where selfValue != toValue && (selfValue == null || !selfValue.Equals(toValue))
```

with

```
where selfValue != toValue && (selfValue == null || !PublicInstancePropertiesEqual(selfValue, toValue, ignore))
```